# Cannot delete a TeeChart series (Delphi XE4)

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-xe4

I've been running the trial version of TeeChart Pro (v.2013.08.130521 32bit VCL) with Delphi XE4 Update 1 on Windows 7 64bit. I have a TDBChart set up and use the "edit chart" dialog to add the series and make the data connection to my dataset.

When I add a series to my chart (I've been using a line series) I can display the data just fine but I cannot delete the series afterwards through the "edit chart" tool. I'm able to remove series during runtime but not design time. When I try to delete the series the IDE hangs and I have to eventually kill the process.

Has anyone else seen this behavior and is there a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce it with the following example that uses *orders* table in *TeeChart Pro Database* shipped with the TeeChart installation and I don't get any error when pressing the button that deletes the series.

```
uses Bde.DBTables, VclTee.Series;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var Table1: TTable;
begin
  Table1:=TTable.Create(Self);
  with Table1 do
  begin
    DatabaseName:='TeeChart Pro Database';
    TableName:='orders';
  end;

  DBChart1.View3D:=false;
  DBChart1.Legend.Visible:=false;

  with DBChart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries) as TLineSeries do
  begin
    DataSource:=Table1;
    XValues.DateTime:=true;
    XValues.ValueSource:='SALEDATE';
    YValues.ValueSource:='AMNTPAID';
  end;

  Table1.Active:=true;
end;

procedure TForm1.BRemoveFirstSeriesClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if DBChart1.SeriesCount>0 then
    DBChart1.RemoveSeries(DBChart1[0]);
end;
```

I only added a TDBChart and a TButton at design time onto the form. The rest is done with the code above.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it's a problem with my setup as this works for me.